# ubuntu 10.04 Wireless is not working in Toshiba satellite pro C850-15Q

Tags: wireless

ubuntu 10.04 Wireless is not working in Toshiba satellite pro C850-15Q Laptop but ubuntu 14.04  takes the wireless driver automaticaly,how to solve wireless problem in ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1):

Try

**sudo service network-manager restart**

Or try this one

**rfkill unblock all**